# Mouseover text in a PDF file generated from python with matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, hyperlink, mouseover

In a PDF file, when you place your mouse over a link, a mouseover text appears (in my PDF reader, in a yellow box). Is it possible to include this type of element in a PDF file generated from python with matplotlib? I want to get this mouseover text over a point of a figure and without a link to a website in the text.

How can I do, starting with the following code?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 10
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y,label='http://website.com')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
fig.savefig("myfig.pdf")
```

You can see the mouseover text box over the link in the legend in the generated PDF file myfig.pdf.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Links in PDF are very simple, and do not allow to add a mousetip text. Instead of that, the active element allowing you to display a mousetip text is a form element, primarily a Button.